# RFID SL2 ICS53 / ISO 15693, unknown error on writing

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I am currently trying to create an android app to edit rfid tags. The tag I am trying to write is an NXP SL2 ICS53. (datasheet http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SL113730.pdf)

It respects the standard ISO-156933. (http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SL113730.pdf)

It's an NfcV tag. (google "android NfcV", reputation limitation... --')

My current problem, as says the title, is that I've been unable to write content on the tag.
I can read the tag using android.nfc.tech.NfcV.transceive() to pass the following command to the tag.

```
22:20:36:F5:A0:03:00:02:04:E0:00 -> in addressed mode
22 -> Addressed, fast data rate
20 -> Read command
36:F5:A0:03:00:02:04:E0 -> UID of the chip (addressed mode requires it)
00 -> Block 0 to read
```

The tag answers :
00:41:4C:46:49, 00 meaning no error, and 41:4C:46:49 being the content of the first block.

I could also read it using the non-addressed mode :

```
02:20:00 -> in non-addressed mode
02 -> Fast data rate
20 -> Read command
00 -> Block 0 to read
```

With this, I get the same answer.

But once I wanted to write, I sent the following, which is supposed to write 00:00:00:00 in the first block (00).

```
02:21:00:00:00:00:00 -> in non-addressed mode
02 -> Fast data rate
21 -> Write command
00 -> Block 0 to write
00:00:00:00 -> Data 00:00:00:00 to write

22:21:36:F5:A0:03:00:02:04:E0:00:00:00:00:00 -> in addressed mode
22 -> Addressed, fast data rate
21 -> Write command
36:F5:A0:03:00:02:04:E0 -> UID of the chip (addressed mode requires it)
00 -> Block 0 to write
00:00:00:00 -> Data 00:00:00:00 to write
```

But according to the Section 8.4 "Error handling" of the first pdf document, the chip answered 01:0F in the addressed mode, which corresponds to "01 -> Error | 0F -> Unknown error", and did not answer in non-addressed mode. It did not write on the tag, as when I read again after, the content hasn't changed. I also used the read command with option flag to verify wether the blocks were protected, and as said the NXP Tag Reader app, they are all "public". What did I do wrong ? Why do I get this error ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try sending command 0xB8 "Get multiple block protection status" (section 8.1.3.8 of the linked PDF)? May be the block is password protected.

Answer (score 0):

Try also to send the option flag which is

```
0x40 // option flag
0x02 // fast data rate
```

so:

```
42:21:00:...
```

This worked for me, but only teste in non-addressed mode!